# wget / curl binaries onto OpenShift before dependencies installation

Tags: python, oracle, openshift, hook

I'm trying to perform a clean installation of an Oracle client onto a, OpenShift POD, just before that the dependencies are installed (in my case python requirements.txt), Oracle installation has to be present to install cx_Oracle.

How can I automatize this process? Can I simply add a line in one of the action_hooks?

Thanks.

Comment: I may be splitting hairs on what you mean by 'install', but with cx_Oracle 6 you don't need any Oracle header or libs to be present when you install cx_Oracle.  (Also, wheels are available so you may not need to build - this makes it easier).  You only need Oracle libs present when you run a Python script that requires cx_Oracle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenShift 3 has no concept of action hooks like OpenShift 2.

To achieve what you want to do, you will need to do the following.

Create a directory `.s2i/bin` in your application source code repository.

In that directory create a file called `assemble`. Add into that file:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eo pipefail

# Add steps here to install Oracle client libraries and header files.
# Install these in a new subdirectory under /opt/app-root. Lets assume
# you use /opt/app-root/oracle.

# ...

# Set and export whatever environment variables you need to set
# to have cx_Oracle when installed pickup header files and libraries
# from under /opt/app-root/oracle. So that Oracle shared libraries
# are found when the Python application is later run, this should
# include setting LD_RUN_PATH environment variable to compile the
# directory where the Oracle libraries are located into the module
# when it is built.

export LD_RUN_PATH=/opt/app-root/oracle/lib

# ...

# Run the original assemble script.

/usr/libexec/s2i/assemble
```

Make sure this `assemble` script is executable.

```
chmod +x .s2i/bin/assemble
```

If `cx_Oracle` comes as binary Python wheels and doesn't need to be compiled, the `LD_RUN_PATH` trick above will not work. In that case also do the following.

In the `.s2i/bin` directory add a `run` script. Add into that file:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eo pipefail

# Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to directory containing
# the Oracle client libraries.

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/app-root/oracle/lib

# Run the original run script, ensuring exec is used.

exec /usr/libexec/s2i/run
```

Make sure this script is executable.

```
chmod +x .s2i/bin/run
```

If you need to access the pod by a terminal and run scripts that need Oracle, be aware that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` wouldn't be set if you relied on that way, so the Oracle libs will not be found. In that case it may be better to add a `.s2i/environment` file and add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` setting there.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/app-root/oracle/lib
```

By being set in `.s2i/environment`, the environment variable will be set in the image and will always be set, even when accessing the pod using a terminal.

Keep in mind that the S2I build process runs as a non root user and thus why you need to install anything under a new subdirectory of `/opt/app-root`.

Comment: Thanks I was on this way !

Comment: My issue with 'hooks' is now gone, but I still got a common issue `ImportError: libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` , and I might have missed something in your instruction (very complete by the way). Do you have any clue on this? I've added LD_LIBRARY_PATH in environment in .s2i folder, I've been able to install cx_Oracle, but I can't import it without having this error message...

Comment: What did you set ``LD_LIBRARY_PATH`` to? What directory is ``libclntsh.so.11.1`` getting installed into? It is that directory which should be used as value to ``LD_LIBRARY_PATH``. Also confirm that ``LD_LIBRARY_PATH`` is set by using ``oc debug dc/yourappsdeploymentconfigname``. This will start a pod with your image and give you a shell in it. You can run ``env`` and look around in the image directories to see where things were installed.

Comment: libclntsh.so.11.1 is installed under /opt/app-root/usr/lib/oracle/ which is my `ORACLE_HOME` ,  my LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64:/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME`

Comment: If you have added ``LD_LIBRARY_PATH`` to ``.s2i/environment`` that will not work as ``$`` variables are not expanded when used in ``.s2i/environment`. Try setting and exporting it in ``assemble`` and ``run`` if not doing it there.

Comment: I can now have access to `libclntsh.so.11.1`, which is good ! But now, I've a dependency missing : `libaio.so.1` and as I don't have root access for POD, do you have an idea on how to 'install/link it'?

Comment: That is  harder problem to solve as when using a S2I builder you have no ability to install additional system packages, due to having no ability to do anything as root. The only solution would be to create a derived custom S2I builder. This can be done by having the files on GitHub and then using Docker Hub automated builds to build it for you and store it on Docker Hub. You can then reference the image from Docker Hub when you want to use it. I have though created issue against Python S2I builder to add the libaio library https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-python-container/issues/205

Comment: I finally found a solution to this...Hum,  let's say a workaround.

First I downloaded the rpm executable for libaio : `https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libaio(x86-64)`

Then I extracted the rpm executable with : `tar -xvf libaio-0.3.107-10.el6.x86_64.rpm` , I picked the libaio.so.1.0.1, renamed it to libaio.so.1, then moved it to my $ORACLE_HOME folder. Then started python shell, import cx_Oracle => It works !!!